# flexbox not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, navigation, flexbox

The below flexbox code doesn't work in firefox. It's a horizontal nav list that stretches across the browser width. In all other browsers the li's space out equally, but in firefox they don't. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0em;
}
.flex-container-top {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-item {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="flex-container-top">
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#eastsidedin">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#eastsidedes">Link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#eastsidedri">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#eastsidehap">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example didn't work in Chrome, either.

You need to add `flex: 1` to `.flex-item`. Then it will work:

```
.flex-item {
  flex: 1; /* add this line */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It was working, I think I made an error copying and cleaning it up. But your fix works! Amazing. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! If it works can you mark the question as answered? :)